# ReverseGeocoding Address name in a EN locale only

Tags: android, google-api, rx-java

I am using a small [library](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation) to do a Reverse Geocoding of a location. 
My problem is the location name in my UI (the TextView that I set using the reverse geocoding to the location name such as "Aberdeen, United Kingdom") is in the same language as the default language of the phone such as Bulgarian (if the phone language is in Bulgarian) and everything else in my app is in English.

So I am looking for a way how to set a Locale.ENGLISH (or something similar) to the following method that I am using for getting the location name:

```
Observable<List<Address>> reverseGeocodeObservable;
String locationName = "";
....

 public void getLocationName(){
    reverseGeocodeObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())// use I/O thread to query for addresses
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())// return result in main android thread to manipulate UI
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Address>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"OnError Geocode");
                    locationName = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.location_name_on_error),"unknown");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Address> addresses) {
                    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = addresses.get(0);
                        Log.v(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Locality: "+address.getLocality() + ", CountryName " + address.getCountryName());
                        //check if cityName is null...
                        String cityName = "unknown";
                        if(address.getLocality() != null) {
                            cityName = address.getLocality();
                            //if it is, try to get the subAdmin Area instead...
                        }else if (address.getSubAdminArea() != null){
                            cityName = address.getSubAdminArea();
                        }
                        String countryName = address.getCountryName();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.location_name_on_error),cityName + ", " + countryName);
                        editor.apply();
                        locationName = getString(R.string.location_name, cityName, countryName);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ReverseGeocodeObservable`](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/blob/master/android-reactive-location/src/main/java/pl/charmas/android/reactivelocation/observables/geocode/ReverseGeocodeObservable.java) from your library uses the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to get the address but it uses the Geocoder without Locale. Try to compile your own version of this library and add a Locale property, see [`public Geocoder (Context context, Locale locale)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder(android.content.Context%2C%20java.util.Locale))

Comment: That is a good point. However, I am importing this library using Gradle and I dont know how to include the library otherwise (I have tried in the past but with no luck) :/

Comment: The easiest way is to download the Java code and put it in your project

Comment: But than you have to remove the dependency in your gradle build script ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I may give that a try :)